# Communicating between components in Swing application

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing simple Peer-Server-Peer chat application in Swing. On the client side, there is a 'Client' object responsible for Client-Server communication and 'MainWindow' which is a main jForm.

Upon receiving a message, 'Client' needs to notify the 'MainWindow' about the new message. However, 'MainWindow' is an object created at the start of the program (in my case after the 'Client' is created), so I'm looking for a way of passing 'MainWindow' reference to 'Client'.

I was thinking about creating 'Resource' class with static references to objects I need to communicate with within my app, but it doesn't seem very elegant.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide with code you have tried?

Comment: You'll want to use an [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  This a common approach in Swing so you'll want to get to know it ;).  This also means that `Client` doesn't need to know (directly) about `MainWindow`, bu can provide a call back interface that the `MainWindow` can register to...

Comment: This is how it looks like: the AuthWindow starts 'Client' object, which implements Runnable and then invokes 'MainWindow':

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public interface MessageListener {
    public void notify(Message msg);
}

public class MainWindow implements MessageListener {
    public void notify(Message msg) {
        // UI Action
    }
}

public class Client {
    private MessageListener listener;

    public void setMessageListener(MessageListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

You can use something similar to Publish Subscribe Pattern where `MainWindow` Subscribes to Publisher `Client` and from client whenever you get a message can call `listener.notify` method. Thus the `notify` method in `MainWindow` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Guava's EventBus.
You can use it to communicate between the two classes without them having references to each other.